# Why I`m getting OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: b'/usr/local/bin/git'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, git

I'm doing a programming course (CS50W) and it has a command to submit the project to github automatically. It's called submit50.
When trying to push my code to github through this method, I do:

`submit50 --verbose web50/projects/2020/x/capstone`

And I'm getting the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: b'/usr/local/bin/git'`

I have literally no idea what is happening here. If you could help me out I would be grateful.

Full error with traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/submit50", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('submit50==3.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'submit50')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/submit50/__main__.py", line 147, in main
    user_name, commit_hash, message = lib50.push("submit50", args.slug, CONFIG_LOADER, prompt=prompt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib50/_api.py", line 69, in push
    with authenticate(remote["org"], repo=repo) as user, prepare(tool, slug, user, included):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib50/_api.py", line 326, in prepare
    _run(git(f"add -f {' '.join(shlex.quote(f) for f in included)}"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib50/_api.py", line 703, in _run
    with _spawn(command, quiet, timeout) as child:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib50/_api.py", line 674, in _spawn
    child = pexpect.spawn(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 303, in _spawn
    self.ptyproc = self._spawnpty(self.args, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 315, in _spawnpty
    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py", line 330, in spawn
    raise exception
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: b'/usr/local/bin/git'
Submission cancelled.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Argument list too long" is a Unix-style<sup>1</sup> error that indicates that the arguments to the `exec`-like function are, well, too long.  (The `b'/usr/local/bin/git'` part here is misleading: that's not the part that is too long.)  The `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` prefix strongly suggests that you're on MacOS, which has a Mach-ish kernel that is Unix-based and has [relatively small argument limits](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/execve.2.html):

```
sh-3.2$ sysctl kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

This means that there's a maximum of 256 kiB of argument characters, including the command itself and all the bytes of arguments, including the `\0` byte that terminates each one.  There's often a limit on the length of `argv` itself as well.  The details vary from one system to another.  See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) on the unix.stackexchange.com site, for instance.

It's not immediately clear to me what to do about this.  Looking at the stack trace, we find this pair of lines (which I've split up further for posting purposes here):

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/
        lib/python3.8/site-packages/lib50/_api.py", line 326, in prepare
  _run(git(f"add -f {' '.join(shlex.quote(f) for f in included)}"))
```

which points to the main culprit: a function named `prepare` in the `lib50` library that is part of what your course provided.  This is trying to run a Git command with many file names passed to its `git add` command.  Where did it get the `included` list?  That, we don't know.  If this list were *shorter*, the problem would not occur, but if there is no way for you to shorten the list, knowing this won't help.

Raising `kern.argmax` would help, but it is probably not something you can set.

Using a different OS, with a different (or raise-able) maximum, could help.

The "right answer", though, is probably to have the software itself be smarter.  There's no need to invoke `git add` this particular way, with every file listed as one big `argv` vector.  Indeed, instead of invoking `git add` directly, a *program* should probably be invoking `git update-index` instead.  A Python program should probably be using `update-index` with the `--stdin` and `-z` flags (and any other flags as appropriate for this particular function's intended usage).

---

<sup>1</sup>Other systems now provide Unix-like error numbers as well, even if they're not based on Unix.  This particular one is `E2BIG` or error #7, on MacOS.