# move all new files from staging to working area in a one-liner

Tags: git

Is there an elegant command to reset HEAD all ***new*** files only from the staging area (to be committed list) back to the working area? This happens after I did a `git add -- '*.py'`. A related question is how to add only changes to existing files in the above syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A related question is how to add only changes to existing files in the above syntax.

Commit has a one-letter option for this, `git commit -a`, and add has `-u` to only update existing index entries, not add new ones.

re:

> Is there an elegant command to reset HEAD all new files only from the staging area (to be committed list) back to the working area? This happens after I did a git add -- '*.py'.

@torek's answer's an encyclopedic version of what I'd say, just as an alternate take:

```
git diff-index --diff-filter=A --name-only -z @ | xargs -0 git reset --
```

It's not completely clear what you want "…back to the working area" to mean; if you mean leave the work tree contents alone, so the added stuff's "back to" only being in the work tree, just the plain reset will do. If you mean "reset the working area to the `HEAD` state too", replace `reset` with `rm` in the command, you want those files gone from the index and the work tree.  Remember that the index is just that: an index, a list of names with pointers to content that's been added to the object db.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the first, i.e., just back to only being in the working tree.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

There are some one-line shell commands that will do what I think you want, which you can form into scripts or Git aliases.  See the long answer for details and some caveats and refinements.  The most straightforward of these assumes that you have a Unix/Linux style `xargs`:

```
git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=A | xargs -0 git reset HEAD --
```

which is easily adapted for other status letters.

#### Long

Let's start with this:

- Every commit stores *every* file, as a snapshot.
- More precisely, it stores the copies that are in the index / staging-area (these two names refer to the same Git entity).
- The `git status` command runs two internal `git diff --name-status` operations.  The first one of these compares all the files stored in the `HEAD` commit to all the files stored in Git's index.

So, if a file named `file-new.ext` that is in the index is considered `A`dded ("new"), it must not exist in `HEAD`.  That in turn means that:

```
git reset HEAD -- file-new.ext
```

will simply *remove* the copy of `file.ext` from Git's index.  Meanwhile, if a file named `file-old.ext` is considered `M`modified, it must exist in both `HEAD` and Git's index.  That in turn means that:

```
git reset HEAD -- file-old.ext
```

will copy the committed version of `file-old.ext` back into Git's index.

With these in mind, let's first revisit the phrasing of the question in the title:

> move all new files from staging to working area in a one-liner

The two example files in question (`file-new.ext` and `file-old.ext`) may or may not already exist in the working tree.  They definitely *do* exist in Git's index.  If we were to *move* them from Git's index to the working tree, this might overwrite any different-in-working-tree data that appears in those files, if they are in the working tree right now.  But *moving* them is not what the body of your question supposes:

> to reset HEAD

I assume that this means to run `git reset HEAD`, or do something equivalent, which—as we just noted—really means *copy from the `HEAD` commit to the index / staging-area, which may involve removing from the index / staging-area*.

Since `git reset HEAD` does just what we want—copy from `HEAD` to index, or remove from index if the file does not appear in `HEAD`—and can be run on a per-file basis, it's probably the command to use.  The problem now becomes: how do we supply the correct set of file names?

Shells do have a form of *command substitution:*

```
command1 $(command2)
```

tells the shell to run `command2`, take its output as a series of white-space-delimited words, break those up into individual arguments, and run `command1` as if we'd typed out those arguments.  So:

```
git reset HEAD -- $(command2)
```

would work, if we had a command that listed out the files we wanted to `git reset HEAD`.  The `--` is to make sure that even if `command2` prints a file name like `--mixed`, it won't be treated as an option to `git reset`.

We still need to find `command2`; we'll get back to that in a moment.

There is an obvious flaw here though: what if we have files named `READ ME` and `READ ME TOO`, i.e., that contain a literal space in their actual name?  The shell will split on white space, and treat these as the files `READ`, `ME`, and `TOO`.  [There's a more subtle flaw as well, which is that the length of the argument list to `git reset` is usually limited by the underlying operating system.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64072974/1256452)  Using `xargs` gets around the second one of these:

```
xargs cmd with initial arguments < very-long-list-of-file-names
```

will run `cmd with initial arguments file1 file2 file3`, then `cmd with initial arguments file4 file5 file6`, and so on, clumping together only as many file names as will fit.  The `xargs` command produces the added arguments by reading each name one at a time from its standard input.

This still has some white-space issues though: if the input file lists `READ ME` and then `READ ME TOO`, we still incorrectly run `git reset` with names `READ`, `ME`, and `TOO`, with `READ` and `ME` repeated.  To fix this problem, we can use `xargs -0`, which treats its input as consisting of names delimited by `\0` (ASCII NUL) bytes.  This works well with programs that output file names with `\0` delimiters, such as `find ... -print0`.  It turns out that the Git command we want to use to produce file names has the same kind of option.

Anyway, with that in mind, we can go right back to the fact we noted earlier, that `git status` runs two `git diff` commands.  The first one—which produces the list of files that it calls *staged for commit*—compares `HEAD` vs the index.  We can run `git diff --name-status` ourselves, manually, to get this same list, in a slightly different format.  We will need the `--cached` flag, which directs `git diff` to compare `HEAD` vs Git's index.<sup>1</sup>

In the output of `git diff --name-status`, we would see, e.g.:

```
A       file-new.ext
M       file-old.ext
```

The *status letter* at the front is from a relatively short menu of possible letters: `A` means `A`dded, i.e., a totally-new file, and `M` means `M`odified.  That's good: the status letter would let us pick out the added files only.  But then we still have to slice up the rest of the input line.  This is usually not too difficult—Git prints the letter, then a tab, then the file name terminated with a newline—but if we want to avoid white space complications in names, we have some nice alternatives:

- `--diff-filter=letters` lets us tell `git diff` to print *only* those lines that start with one of those letter codes, so `git diff --diff-filter=A` means print *only* the `A`dded files;
- `--name-only` tells `git diff` to suppress the status-code letter itself (it's still generated internally, it's just not printed); and
- `-z` tells `git diff` to produce machine-readable output suitable for `xargs`.

Putting these together, we get:

```
git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=A
```

to print out just the `A`dded files (`--diff-filter`)—or rather just their names (`--name-only`)—from the results of a comparison of `HEAD` vs the index (`--cached`), in a form suitable for the zero flag (`-z`) of the `xargs` program.  So then we merely need to pipe that to `xargs -0`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>If you prefer, you can use the `--staged` flag, which means the same thing.  I tend to use `--cached` because `git rm` still does not have a `--staged` alias for `--cached`.  These use the *third* name for Git's index: older Git documentation occasionally refers to it as the *cache*.  One command, `git apply`, tries to distinguish between the index (`git apply --index`) and the cache (`git apply --cached`), but overall I think this is just a little *too* tricky: `--index` here means *both the index copy and the working tree copy* while `--cached` means *the index copy only*.

<sup>2</sup>The fact that the flag is `-z` to Git commands, but `-0` to `xargs` itself, is a minor annoyance.  You just have to memorize this, or check the documentation regularly.

---

#### Caveats / considerations

The `git diff` command is very nice, but it has a feature that *might* be a flaw, if you turn this into a script.  It is what the Git documentation calls a *porcelain* command.  This means it obeys user configuration, i.e., items you can set with `git config`.

One user configuration item that's particularly important here is the setting of `diff.renames`.  If `diff.renames` is set to `true`, a `git diff` will look for *renamed* files.

Renaming, in Git, is a matter of detection-after-the-fact.  That is, while there is a `git mv` command, `git mv` does not actually *record* a rename.  It just erases one in-the-index name and creates another different one, to hold the file's content.  That way, after `git mv old new`, your *next* commit *lacks* a file named `old`, but *has* a file named `new`.  The *content* of the file `old` in the current commit will match the content of the file `new` in the new commit, provided of course you do not change the index copy's content as well.

So, given any two commits, `git diff` just lays out all the left-side commit's file names, and all the right-side commit's file names:

- If there is a file named `this-name-did-not-change` on *both sides*, it assumes that this is the *same file*, and just looks at it to see what, if anything, changed *within* the file.
- If the left side had a file named `removeme`, and the right side has all the same files except that `removeme` is gone, the diff will say that this file was removed.
- If the left side has 100 files in it, and the right side has 101 files, with 100 of them having the same names and the 101st having the name `new-file`, the diff will say that the new file was added.
- But—here's the rename detector in action—suppose the left and right sides both have 100 files, while 99 of those files have the same names.  Meanwhile on the left, the file named `old` has no right-side file named `old`, and on the right, there is a new file named `new`.  Git will now *compare the content* of the old file named `old` to the new file named `new`.

If the two files are *sufficiently similar*,<sup>3</sup> Git will now claim that one of the differences—maybe the only difference—from the old commit to the new commit is that the file `old` was *renamed* to become the file `new`.  The status letter for this is `R`, and `git diff` will print both file names with this status letter.  (This means that `git diff -z` output has to be machine-interpreted very carefully, if you allow `R` status!)

Besides realizing that `git diff` always picks up on renames as an after-the-fact test—and that a file is considered renamed only if it is "sufficiently similar" (see footnote 3 again)—the key consideration here is that `git diff` will only even *look* for a rename **if the rename detector is turned on**.  If it *is* on, you can get an `R` letter with two file names.  If it is off, you will get a `D` for the left-to-right "deleted" file and an `A` for the left-to-right "added" file, instead of one `R` with the left-side name as the old name, and the right-side name as the new name.

So, when is the rename detector turned on?  Well, the `--find-renames` option turns it on, but we did not use that in our `git diff` command.  But `git diff` is a *porcelain* command, so it obeys user configuration.  If the user has set `diff.renames` to `true`, the rename detector is *also* turned on, unless we add `--no-find-renames`.  If the user has set `diff.renames` to `false`, the rename detector is *off*, unless we use `--find-renames`.  So if we want to be very specific, we could add `--find-renames` or `--no-find-renames`.

Most of the time this won't matter, but if we have both newly created files *and* some deleted files, or if we have run `git mv` or otherwise fiddled with the names in Git's index,<sup>4</sup> `git diff --cached` might decide that some file is *renamed*, rather than finding that one file is deleted and another file is newly-added.

To work around this per-user behavior—if you indeed *want* to work around it; perhaps you *prefer* it—you can:

- add an explicit flag, `--find-renames` or `--no-find-renames`; or
- use `git -c diff.renames=setting` to force a setting; or
- use the *plumbing command* `git diff-index --cached HEAD` to compare `HEAD` vs the index.

This last option, using `git diff-index --cached HEAD`, is like running `git diff --cached`, except that it does not read the user's configuration, and the rename detector is always off *unless* you add `--find-renames` to the arguments.

Note that in the absence of a `diff.renames` *setting*, the rename detector defaults to off in Git versions predating Git 2.9, but defaults to on (for porcelain commands) in Git 2.9 and later.

---

<sup>3</sup>How similar is *sufficient?*  How is similarity even *measured?*  That's a topic for a separate question, but it's worth noting that if the old and new files are a 100% byte-for-byte match, the rename detector will always declare the file to be renamed, *and* will work very fast.  If there is even a single byte difference, it will work more slowly.

<sup>4</sup>The `git mv` command is just a *nice* way to adjust things; there's a plumbing command, `git update-index`, that can do just about anything.